# GlassFish 5 Valid SSL Certificate SLOW https ERROR Write timeout exceeded when trying to flush the data

Tags: ssl, glassfish-5

Hi All can validate my implementation of SSL over glassfish PLEASE ?

I have a domain cloud3.dyalogodev.com into my glassfish server.

The SSL its ok charge but the render of my application is very slow, can you test.

https://cloud3.dyalogodev.com:8182/dyalogocbx/

BUt without https is fast:

http://cloud3.dyalogodev.com:8081/dyalogocbx/

```
In addition the server throw an error:

java.io.IOException: Write timeout exceeded when trying to flush the data
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:1023)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:154)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1309)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1285)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter$2.run(Http2ServerFilter.java:1033)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:154)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1309)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1285)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter$2.run(Http2ServerFilter.java:1033)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed
```

PLEASE HELP ME, THanks advance.

Comment: I just tried your https link and the response time was great! Is the issue fixed, or is the problem intermittent?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, try in mozilla firefox please.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that I also occasionally see long delays rendering other https links when using Firefox, most notably for google news (https://news.google.com/gn/news/headlines?hl=en&ned=us&gl=US). While it is possible that there are issues with your code, that seems unlikely for a heavily used google URL. However, the distinction is that other https URLs rarely load slowly in Firefox, but yours always does.  The delay when loading the google news page was during **CC Graph Reduction**, similar to that shown for your page in my screen shot below.

Comment: Tried if it is not by accident an http/2 issue? https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=55581&p=168499#p168499

Comment: If I disable http/2 the SSL one is quick too (slower than http though). For me it takes 10-15 seconds in both FireFox (60.0.2) and Chrome (67.0.3396.99) with http/2 and 3 seconds with http/1.1 (both ssl)  and with http/2 I see resources failing loading in both FF and Chrome

Comment: With my VPN turned off (no company forced 'transparant' proxy) the http/2 and http/1.1 are both quick 3 seconds btw

Comment: I have the same issue like you, please let me know what's the real problem is and how to solve it if you find out why, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT a solution to your interesting problem, but I need more space than the comments allow to provide some feedback.

- On a Windows 10 machine I tried the URL https://cloud3.dyalogodev.com:8182/dyalogocbx/ in several browsers: Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera and Vivaldi.
- The response was fast in all browsers except Firefox where the response took about a minute to complete.
- Using **Web Developer > Performance** I captured [the Waterfall output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Waterfall). See the screen shot below.
- It seems that almost all the time is being spent in various phases of Garbage Collection (**CC Graph Reduction**, **Non-incremental GC**, **Minor GC** and **Cycle Collection**), or transitions between those phases. The screen shot shows that about 16 seconds was spent doing nothing but **CC Graph Reduction** which Mozilla describes as "*Preparation/pre-optimization for Cycle Collection*". Something is clearly wrong for that to be taking so long.
- Note that at the bottom of the screen shot there are also a couple of warnings

  1. Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cloud3.dyalogodev.com:8182/dyalogocbx/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.0”.
  2. TypeError: this.jq.draggable is not a function[Learn More]
- The information above is only descriptive, not diagnostic. I have no idea what is causing the problem. Perhaps you could simplify the code in your JSF page, and then if the performance problem goes away progressively reintroduce the complexity.
- I think this problem may be more suitable for a Mozilla forum or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) than Stack Overflow.

[image: waterfallSnapshot]

Comment: Is normal that speed reduce when enable SSL ? I read several blogs and say this.

Comment: When SSL is enabled there is more operations done so yes it is normal that the speed reduce

Comment: Firefox is for me on par with Chrome on this site.